# Android sharing image from browser

Tags: android, browser, share

I'm working in a project which contain external browser image sharing. When i shared the image from browser i got only empty string not an complete url.

in android **manifest** file

```
  <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in **java** class

```
if (getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
        String text_data = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.e("IMAGE--", text_data);//getting only empty string
    }
```